# How to Deploying Spring Boot Applications on live server and make database connections with mysql

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, jsp

How to Deploying Spring Boot Applications on live server and  make database connections with mys sql.
please give me better suggestion so i can move forward with that server.if you can Please suggest me any article or video so i can follow that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You flagged your question with `amazon-web-services`. So do you know the `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` service?

https://aws.amazon.com/de/elasticbeanstalk/

It makes it really easy to deploy your web application into AWS. Here is also a tutorial on how you connect your SQL database to your application:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html